# Placeholder for Observable?

Tags: rx-java

Lets say that I have two Observables A and B.
A emits true when a service is connected to my program. B emits true if the service is started, else false.

I want to combine A and B using combineLatest and then take appropriate action.

The problem is that B is not available until I have connected to the service. So my question is if I can have an Observable-wrapper och placeholder for B until B is available? Then when B is available the wrapper should emit those values coming from B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with a simple solution.

I created a Subject C, like this

```
BehaviorSubject<Boolean> C = BehaviorSubject.create(false);
```

By doing this I was able to something like this

```
Observable.combineLatest(A, C, bla bla....
```

then when B become available I do

```
B.subcribe(C);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can achieve that using delaySubscription. Here's an example:

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
Future<Void> future = executorService.submit(() -> {
  Thread.sleep(3000);
  //service started
  return null;
});
Observable<Void> oFuture = Observable.from(future, Schedulers.newThread());
Observable<Long> oA = Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
Observable<Long> oB = Observable.interval(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
Observable<Long> delayedObservable = oB.delaySubscription(new Func0<Observable<Void>>() {
  @Override public Observable<Void> call() {
    return oFuture;
  }
});
Observable<String> stringObservable = Observable.combineLatest(oA, delayedObservable, (i1, i2) -> i1 + "-" + i2);
executorService.submit(() -> {
  stringObservable.forEach(System.out::println);
});
Thread.sleep(10000);
executorService.shutdownNow();
```

Comment: Thank you, I came up with a simpler solution, see my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

What you are really saying is that B depends on A. Most of the time when you have one observable that depends on another you can use .flatMap() to express that relationship.

```java
Observable<Boolean> createObservableA() {
    return ...; // Same as you currently have for creating Observable A.
}

Observable<Boolean> createObservableB() {
    return createObservableA()
        .flatMap(serviceConnected -> {
            if (!serviceConnected) {
                // Don't emit anything to subscribers yet.
                return Observable.empty();
            }

            return ...; // Service is now connected create Observable B.
        });
}
```